# Prevent duplicate traces within this code for I and V?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, yaxis

Here is my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel (r'filename', sheet_name='sheetname', header=0, usecols=[2,7,8,19,20,21],names=['t','I','V','T1','T2','T3'])

ax = df.plot(x='t',y=["I","V",])
df.plot(x='t',secondary_y=["T1","T2","T3",], ax1=ax)

plt.show()
```

The code above will produce a graph but with two traces for I and V, one trace for T1 - T3. How would I change the code to eliminate the duplicate traces for I and V?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7oBQ.png)

Comment: Can you do ```df.to_dict()``` and paste the result in your question? Adding data to test solutions may imporove your chances to get an answer.

Comment: The Output link in the original question shows the graphical output i get. Apologies, never posted before!

Comment: Using the below code rectifies my issue!

ax = df.plot(x='t',y=["I","V",])
ax1=ax.twinx()
df.plot(x='t',secondary_y=["T1","T2","T3",], ax=ax1)

plt.show()

Comment: Would delete if any appropriate feedback given as to why the question was downgraded. Ridiculous!